# How to vertically center the Menu control within a div in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

I am working in asp.net webforms. I have a Menu control within a div element. Somehow the menu doesn't stay within the div. It is either at the bottom of the div or outside of it. I essentially want to keep the div to be height 30px and the Menu to be displayed vertically at the center. The following is my code:

```
    <div id="mainnav" style="height:30px">
    <asp:Menu ID="menuBarMaster" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="100%"  
            CssClass="flyout-menu" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10"   ClientIDMode="Static" 
            StaticPopOutImageUrl = "images/blue_right_arrow_silk.png" 
            DynamicPopOutImageUrl = "images/blue_right_arrow_silk_small.png">               
            <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="staticMenuItem" />   
            <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="staticHoverStyle"></StaticHoverStyle>             
            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="staticMenuItemStyle" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticSelectedStyle" />              
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuItemStyle" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="dynamicHoverStyle" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuStyle" />
        </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it certain width and set margin: 0 auto;

```
<div id="mainnav" style="height:30px; background: #000; width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <asp:Menu ID="menuBarMaster" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"  Width="100%"
    CssClass="flyout-menu" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="10"   ClientIDMode="Static"
    StaticPopOutImageUrl = "images/blue_right_arrow_silk.png"
    DynamicPopOutImageUrl = "images/blue_right_arrow_silk_small.png">
    <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="staticMenuItem" />
    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="staticHoverStyle"></StaticHoverStyle>
    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="staticMenuItemStyle" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticSelectedStyle" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuItemStyle" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="dynamicHoverStyle" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuStyle" />
  </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

Vertical alignment can be done via setting the parent div to relative position and child (mainnav) has absolute with the following margins and certain height of 30px;.

set to your parent of #mainnav element position: absolute;

your #mainnav should also have:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 30px;
```

You will probably need to play with right: 0; left: 0;

Comment: This will center the menu horizontally But I need to center vertically. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this trick I learned long ago :

First Sets the width and height of the menu .

Second set top: 50 % and position: absolute .

Third set margin-top : -height / 2.

Example

```
<HTML>
<Head><title>A page</title></Head>
<Body>
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px; background-color: blue; position: absolute;">
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; top: 50%; margin-top: -50px; position: absolute;">

</div>
</div>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

If you want to center horizontal too, then you have to set margin-left: -width/2 and done!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to vertically center an element inside of some other container. [CSS Tricks has a great writeup](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) on the different options, including when you can/should use each one.

The most general answer, which assumes the parent is of unknown height and the child is a block-level element, uses relative and absolute positioning, similar to the answers above.

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```